How to add period count antd-vue calendar?
I use ant design. Here I have a simple component:
<a-calendar :locale="calendarLocale" class="px-2 rounded" bordered>
        <template #dateCellRender="{ current }">
          <ul class="flex flex-col gap-2">
            <li v-for="item in getListData(current)" :key="item.id">
              <a-badge :status="item.type" :text="item.title" class="line-clamp-2" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </template>
      </a-calendar>

I want to add display count props. Here show only one month days (when mode="month"). Is it possible to show 2 or 3 months?

If you can't see this in docs, you can't, but probably could customize the comp to do this . But what do you expect this to look like? Could it be just several a-calendar instances in a row?
